# Is trimming the hair below the bottom lip allowed?

Tags: sunnah, taharah, beard, fitrah

I follow the Hadith where it is said to "Leave / grow the beard and trim moustache". I have hair growing right below my lower lip; some brothers have a big hairless gap there either they don't grow hair there or have shaved / trimmed it. Is this allowed? I heard that that area isn't actually the beard so you can remove.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/ar/109265), there are two opinions, the strongest of which is that it isn't considered part of the beard and therefore shaving it is permissible.